# APEX in oracle 12c

Tags: database, oracle, oracle-apex

I've already installed oracle DB 12c enterprise edition. And I can't find any tutorial or something like that for connecting to APEX throught browser.
What should I do in order to get inside APEX? I need detailed answer

Comment: Have you installed Apex? Enterprise Edition doesn't include Apex. You need to download and install Apex separately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you taken a look at the oracle documentation regarding the installation? It's pretty much straight forward and contains several scenarios:

http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/HTMIG/overview.htm#CEGEGBAE